# how to do DAO(db) layer unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, tdd

since the dao layer methods will be dependent on data in the database, 
in complex systems some operations will depend on lots of tables,
in this way unit test are not repeatable and independent,

i'm wondering how good TDD layers do this? thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A testing framework like [DbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) is exactly what you want.  From their site:

> DbUnit is a JUnit extension (also usable with Ant) targeted at database-driven projects that, among other things, puts your database into a known state between test runs. This is an excellent way to avoid the myriad of problems that can occur when one test case corrupts the database and causes subsequent tests to fail or exacerbate the damage.

DbUnit also [supports](http://dbunit.wikidot.com/supportedrdbms) a variety of RDBMS's but I might recommend something like [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), which can be embedded into your project/tests so your unit tests aren't dependent on being able to connect to a database somewhere in your company's basement.  :)  Although, on the other hand, you will be testing using a different RDBMS than you would be using in a production environment...

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you are on to something... If you are communicating with your Sql Server, then you are not doing unit test but integration tests. If you do TDD, then you realise this and start to put server communication into wrappers, so you can stub and mock any test data, instead of using a framework like DbUnit to control database state. I think that Your business logic should not be directly in touch with databases -- or webservices or other external resources. If it is, odds are that you will never write anything but integration tests.

Comment: It's true that tests like these are more like integration tests, but regardless of what label you put on it, there may still be a need for testing.  As I mentioned in my response, embedding an RDBMS like HSQLDB will take server communication out of the equation, but are there better ways of making sure things like ORM's are worked as intended?  Is there an alternative to something like DbUnit that will still give you accurate feedback on whether tweaking that Hibernate mapping broke something?